# New oven door insulation visible

Tags: kitchens, oven

I have had a new oven installed. One side of the door hinge has insulation coming out slightly. It may have gotten slightly discolored from use. Is this normal and safe, or should the insulation be tucked away?

[image]

Comment: A new oven?  Send that picture to the manufacturer.   If they are any good, they will have a local tech come out and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an issue. Poke it further in with a pencil or trim it off if it's pinched. No need to drag a technician out for a bit of fluff.